# ssh connection check to remote hots Linux

Tags: bash, ssh

I am trying to write a bash script to check if ssh is working via `bash` but below script only logs in to first host but it does not do what i need.

```
#!/bin/bash
USERNAME=user1
file="/home/user1/HOST"
HOSTS=$(cat "$file")
RCODE=$?

for linux_hosts in ${HOSTS} ;
do
    ssh -q $linux_hosts -l ${USERNAME} -o BatchMode=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
    exit 0

    if [ $RCODE -ne 0 ]
      then
      echo "unable to ssh, host is not accessible"
    else:
      echo "Host is responding to ssh, host is accessible"
    fi
done
```

**HOST File:**

```
cat /home/user1/HOST
Server1
Server2
Server3
Server4
```

Expected:

I need to Just check if host is able to get ssh, Like below..

```
Server1: Host is responding to ssh, host is accessible
Server2: Host is responding to ssh, host is accessible
Server3: Host is not responding to ssh, host is not accessible
Server4: Host is not responding to ssh, host is not accessible
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: `exit 0` inside the `for` loop causes the script to exit without processing the other hosts.

Comment: `RCODE=$?`, then some code, then `[ $RCODE -ne 0 ]` will not do what you think it does.

Comment: Tip: Use [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) to find a number of bugs in your code.

Comment: @Biffen, thnx a lot for the hint  and feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it can be short enough if your aim is Just to validate the ssh connection.

```
#/bin/bash

for server in $(cat /home/user1/HOST)
do
   if ssh $server "true" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectTimeout=2
      then
      echo "$server   : Host is responding to ssh, host is accessible"
   else
      echo "$server   : Host is not responding to ssh, host is accessible"
   fi
done
```

Comment: thnx i will check and let you know.